# How to Prevent Default action of Mousewheel event

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm working on building a d3.js bar chart that will allow me to scroll on the x axis by wrapping an svg element with fixed width and heigh inside of smaller div with overflow properties. This visualization is being built on a platform that handles the data and provides a javascript code editor to create the visualization. Once you publish the code, the bar chart renders in an html div element.

The page where the bar chart gets rendered has a default zoom event that fires when you use the mousewheel. Since I would like to scroll in my bar chart by using the mousewheel, I'm trying to stop the default zoom action from firing by included the following statement in the code:

```
$(vizhtmlelement).mousewheel(function() {
    return false;
});
```

This works successfully at removing the zoom functionality, but it also prevents the scrolling with the mousewheel from working. Is there a way I can stop the mousewheel zoom from happening while keeping the mousewheel scroll in my visualization?

Comment: are you looking for `event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 1):

On whatever element you .call() your zoom function, you need to set its mousewheel behavior to null. So if you .call(zoom) from a  or  with the id of "yourElement" then it would look like this:

```
d3.select("#yourElement")
.call(myZoom)
.on("dblclick.zoom", null)
.on("mousewheel.zoom", null)
.on("DOMMouseScroll.zoom",null);
```

Notice I also disabled the double-click zoom, because you'll probably want that disabled as well.

Comment: Hi Elijah, thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, don't have control over the zoom function. It's already called by default on the entire page.

Comment: As far as I can tell, backbone.js is being used and in one of the initialize() properties, a function zoomHammer is being called: `this._zoomHammer = this.$content.zoomHammer(this.options).data("zoomHammer");`. This zoomHammer function has the following line: `el.data('zoomHammer', new Zoomable(this, options || {}));`. The Zoomable functions then calls an enable function that contains: `this.$root().on('mousewheel', function (ev, delta) {
                    ev.preventDefault();
                    return instance._handleWheel(ev, delta);
                });`

Comment: Ah, I thought this was dealing with the d3.zoom() function. I'm not familiar enough with backbone to know how to override it.